# HQL unexpected AST node:unexpected AST node:

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, orm, abstract-syntax-tree

I got this exception:

```
unexpected AST node: query
```

My query is:

```
SELECT  u.user_id, u.username,u.email,u.phone,u.status,r.rolename 
FROM user_registration u, roles r 
WHERE u.user_id=r.role_id IN (
    select ur.role_id  from roles ur where ur.role_id=u.user_id
)
```

This query runs in MySQL, but it's not working in my application

Exception is:

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/jaga] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: in near line 1, column 196 [SELECT  u.user_id, u.username,u.email,u.phone,u.status,r.rolename FROM com.jagahunt.admin.usermanagement.entity.User u, com.jagahunt.admin.usermanagement.entity.Role r WHERE u.user_id=r.role_id  IN (select ur.role_id  from com.jagahunt.admin.usermanagement.entity.Role ur where ur.role_id=u.user_id)]] with root cause
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: in near line 1, column 196 [SELECT  u.user_id, u.username,u.email,u.phone,u.status,r.rolename FROM com.jagahunt.admin.usermanagement.entity.User u, com.jagahunt.admin.usermanagement.entity.Role r WHERE u.user_id=r.role_id  IN (select ur.role_id  from com.jagahunt.admin.usermanagement.entity.Role ur where ur.role_id=u.user_id)]
```

Comment: `WHERE u.user_id=r.role_id IN(select ...`. That's invalid. Either the user id is equal to something, or it's in a subselect. But you can't concatenate the two restrictions like that.

Answer (score 2):

This is a native query that you are trying to execute.

Therefore, you should use `session.createSQLQuery()` for this, instead of `session.createQuery()` which takes an HQL entity query instead.